# Why are C++ OBJ files important?

Tags: c++

Be warned I am new to C++.

When I compile my program I notice that there is an .obj created for every class that I have. When I looked at other programs in my program files, I realized that these programs barely had any .obj's so I guess that I am doing something wrong.

Also if I deleted the obj files from the release directory and tried to run the exe again and it still worked exactly as before, I know these files can't be pointless but...

What is their use? Should it make them for every class file? - if not how do I resolve this?

How do I put them in one directory like a folder called obj when I compile?

Comment: Those files are generated for use by the linker. You don't need to touch them.

Comment: But if you delete the `.obj` files, then the compiler will need to recompile everything if you edit even one `.cpp` file. Don't delete them from your project directory unless you're sure you don't need them.

Comment: You are not doing any thing wrong. Without the .obj you will not be able to link thus create a .lib .dll or .exe.

Comment: Welcome! Usually we try to avoid thank taglines in the questions to keep them tidier, you can read why in here: ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Hey, I deleted a class in my project (visual c++ 2015), and now it is giving me the error "cannot open Debug/filename.obj  how to solve"

Comment: @JavaManTeaMan clean your project then re build

Comment: @DanielCollier I did do this; still no luck.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`.obj` files (`.o` files on Linux/Unix) are compiled source files, there will indeed be one for each `.cpp` file, or more formally "compilation unit". They are produced by the compilation phase of building a project.

These `.obj` files are then combined by linker either to an application, usually `.exe` file on Windows, or a library file, which on windows can be a `.dll` for dynamic library, or `.lib` for static library (which is basically a collection of `.obj` files in one packed into one file, see below). On Unix-like platform application usually has no extension, and dynamic library has `.so` extension, and static library has `.a` extension.

You do not see `.obj` files or static `.lib` files with programs, because they are not needed at runtime, they are used only by linker. When you run the linking phase of building a project, linker combines all the needed `.obj` files into `.exe` and `.dll` files (or equivalent), which are used at runtime.

Answer (score 9):

[Obj files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) are generated after compiling. The compiler generates them with many information. Then the linker generates an executable with other files, thus those OBJ files are not necessary anymore.

A very extended answer can be found in any C++ book.

There is no problem. But if you delete them you will force your compiler to compile some files that had no changes but have no OBJ file anymore. Be aware of that.

Just forget about them if you are still working in your code.

Comment: I just wrote a half-page C++ "book" and didn't write an extended answer. Therefore you are wrong, and I am forced to downvote you.

Comment: But it is similar to other posts, many many websites, and many other references. 
The point is to redirect to them, not to write them once again.

Comment: The purpose of SO is not to redirect people to resources, but to act as a resource for people.

Comment: Ok. You are right. But maybe, redirect to similar posts inside SO.

Comment: @darkgaze: That should be done with close-as-duplicate, not links ;) However the remainder of your answer is fine.

Comment: Really?... U_U I didn't know i could do that... New things everytime. I wanted to help, anyway. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Object files are generated by compiling your code. They take your code and convert it to machine code so that the computer can understand and implement your solutions. Once the object files have been generated (a object file is generated for every .cpp file), all the relevant object files are used by the compiler to build a executable file. The executable can then be run independant of the object files, and the object files may be deleted. If another executable were to be created, object files for the relevant code would be necessary again.

Hope it helps!