# Why am I getting errors for files that aren't in my project?

Tags: c++

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN7jd.png)
I am getting errors for "main.obj", which isn't part of my project. And the second file, which I am assuming is the built exe, does not exist yet.

I have found the obj file in the "Release" folder, however I cannot figure out what to do to fix the error with it.

Comment: We need more details. For starters, attach the full build log as text (from the 'output' tab).

Comment: Most likely the problem is not with `main.obj` it's telling you that the implementation of a required function is not in the objects or libraries that are linked with your project.

Comment: What environment (IDE etc.) are you using? How is it configured?

Comment: The compiler is producing main.obj from main.c. The error is from the linker, not from the compiler. The linker works with .obj files and library files and produces the exe. So the issue is an "unresolved external symbol" being referenced in main.c (or its includes.) So it is a part of your project - but a file you indirectly created with the compiler not the source file you created.

Comment: In other words, this is usual for this error on windows (object file naming is different on different platforms.) For the error: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/631266)  For another question that shows that the error is reported as from the .obj file: [Unresolved external symbol in object files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9928238/631266)

Comment: The question title being specifically about the obj file you do not recognize but not about the error message, does this (+ the links from previous comment) answer your question? [Why are C++ OBJ files important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140021/why-are-c-obj-files-important)